# Peut-on « élaguer » une famillie génératrice d'un espace vectoriel

Tags: choix-de-mot, terminologie, mathématiques

Si *V* est un espace vectoriel, et *A  = v<sub>1</sub>, v<sub>2</sub>, … , v<sub>n</sub>* est une suite de vecteurs qui engendrent *V*, la suite est dite *génératrice.*  Il y a une sous-suite de la suite ci-dessus qui engendre *V* et est libre à la fois, disons *B = v<sub>k<sub>1</sub></sub>, v<sub>k<sub>2</sub></sub>, … , v<sub>k<sub>m</sub></sub>*, où *k<sub>j</sub>* ne vaut pas *k<sub>i</sub>* dès que *i* ne vaut pas *j*.

Y a-t-il un mot français qu’on peut utiliser au lieu de « remplacer B par une suite semblable à A », « retirer autant de vecteurs jusqu'à ce que la suite soit libre », où encore autrement dit « faire une base à partir de la suite » ?

Chez moi, un mot qui se traduit comme « mincir », ou peut-être « élaguer » a cours, mais je ne sais pas si ces deux mots sont utilisables lorsqu’il s’agit de choisir une partie d'une famille génératrice.

Comment: La question générale porte sur les métaphores et leurs utilisations en maths. Les deux écoles se trouvent. Bien sûr, les matheux les moins littéraires ou se pensant les plus rigoureux pour une meilleur lisibilité (supposée) n'aiment pas cela du tout.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Le terme consacré est *extraire*, en particulier, dans le cas du [théorème qui t'intéresse](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Th%C3%A9or%C3%A8me_de_la_base_incompl%C3%A8te)

> *De toute famille génératrice d'un espace vectoriel on peut extraire une base.*

En passant, l'opération inverse est *compléter* et on a

> *Tout famille libre d'un espace vectoriel peut être complétée en une base.*

---

<sub>En prenant l'axiome du choix, évidemment. Et puis comme ça on peut [multiplier les citrouilles](http://xkcd.com/804/).</sub>